# Problems with ThreadPool.apply_async() inside docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, threadpool

I have a class that performs a multi-threaded copy and MD5 checksum hash. The general flow for a single file copy goes like this:

- load the read buffer, start the loop

  - copy the read buffer to the destination buffer
  - start a new thread to read the next block of data
  - start a new thread to hash the bytes in the destination buffer
  - write the destination buffer to the output file
  - end the loop when the write to the output file was zero bytes or less then the size of the buffer

I recently switched the read thread from threading.Thread() to ThreadPool(processes=1).apply_async() because it was simpler to to a get() on the readpool then have the read thread write to a global variable and do a join() on it after checking if it was isAlive().

Here is my problem!
After I made this change the code worked fine when testing from a terminal window in OS X but as soon as I deployed it to a docker container running Ubuntu it caused a huge performance problem. When copying a folder full of files it would get a couple hundred files into it and just stop running. Troubleshooting the code with a bunch of print statements I narrowed it down to the loop described above and I knew the only thing I recently changed in that loop as the threading of the file reads. Once I switched that back it worked fine again.

Is there some limit on the number of processes a docker container can acquire? Anyone have any ideas what I hit on? I fixed my problem for now but I would love to know what the issue is so I don't do it again.